# How to find if else blocks fast in Emacs

Tags: emacs

If I have code that has a lot of if/then/else conditions like so:

```
if () {
if () {

} else {

}
} else {
if () {

} else {

}
}
```

and there might also be a lot of text inside those conditions.  How can I quickly find the outermost `if` as well as the corresponding `else`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `backward-up-list` (bound to <kbd>C-M-up</kbd>) to work my way up the nested blocks to the `if` I'm interested in, then use `forward-sexp` (bound to <kbd>C-M-right</kbd>) when on the left bracket to jump over the block to the `else`.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving by parentheses: M-C-b (back), M-C-f (forward), M-C-n (next), M-C-p.  Don't be afraid to just move the point to the top of the buffer and isearch forward.  You can also move by defuns and other constructs.